# Help me identify the structure of this excerpt

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

"Girls being kept out of the sciences and pushed into the humanities; the humanities being valued less in our society than the sciences;... "

This sentence is weird and I want to know why. I noticed "being" has no helping verb. The semicolons delineate subjects; it reads like a list.

My questions: What is the structure? Is this passive? What is the verb tense? Is there an object? Why is this terrible?
Thank you.

edit:

Here is the full quote:

> Girls **being** kept out of the sciences and pushed into the
>   humanities; the humanities **being** valued less in our society than
>   the sciences; and the humanities and sciences **being** looked at as
>   stark opposites **that couldn’t possibly be** enjoyed for the same
>   reasons
>
> are all problems that need to in some degree be tackled together.

All the "beings" stick out to me, as do the excessive semicolons. The transition from the final "being" into the "couldn't possible be" is strange, (is there a tense switch?), and then it ends weakly.

Comment: There is no tense in this, for there are no finite verbs.  In fact, there is no complete sentence in that excerpt.  *Being* is a present participle.

Comment: I suspect that these clauses are each subjects to the main verb, which is excluded in the `...` of the quote. Please post the whole sentence; use bold to indicate what you're concerned about. It might even help to include a sentence either side as well.

Comment: Also, the use of semicolons (as supercommas?) seems unwarranted.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: +1 That, or an absolute construction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Style guides permit such semicola if the (non-clausal) elements of an enumeration are very long.

Comment: @Cerberus I use them myself when there are other commas around, but commas would do here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I suppose they might. But length can also be a valid reason, I'd say.

Comment: @Cerberus Length doesn’t matter.

Comment: @tchrist: So they always say...

Comment: @Anonym When it acts as a nominal we call the *-ing* form a gerund, not a present participle.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm aware, but this usage seems more participial than gerundial.

Comment: @Anonym: "Being X, being Y and being Z are all problems" - those have to be nominal.

Comment: @StoneyB But that isn't the construction here.  It's *X being A, Y being B, and Z being C are all problems.*

Comment: @Anonym But *being* is the head of each clause. Girls and the humanities aren't the problems; the problems are *them-**being**-pushed*, and girls and the humanities are just the subjects of the verb. Yes, an ACC-subject gives a somewhat less nouny feeling to the gerund than a GEN-subject; but it's still called a gerund.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps rich-text would help:

> The following
>
> - girls being kept out of the sciences and pushed into the humanities
> - the humanities being valued less in our society than the sciences
> - the humanities and sciences being looked at as stark opposites that couldn’t possibly be enjoyed for the same reasons
>
> are all problems that need to in some degree be tackled together.

It's a list of three long noun-phrases, then "are", then a [predicate complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement).

Comment: ....... Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it does indeed read as a list of noun phrases. There is no main verb present in the excerpt that you have posted but as Andrew Leach suggests it may appear later in the sentence.

'being' is part of a passive reduced relative clause, 'girls being kept' possibly substituting for 'girls who are being kept' (although the time frame is not clear in the excerpt). The implied tense of this relative clause might thus be present continuous passive. This type of reduction (i.e. in which you remove the relative pronoun and 'are/is') is quite common with defining relative clauses containing continuous forms.

I think it might be best to describe 'being' itself as a 'helping verb', if by 'helping verb' you mean 'auxiliary verb'. The meaning verbs (or semantic verbs) in these relative clauses are 'kept', 'pushed' and 'valued', each in past participle form, with 'being' providing the other ingredient necessary for the construction of the passive: be + past participle.

Hope that is helpful. All the best!

[This site explains reduced relative clauses pretty well!](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/reduced-relative-clauses-lesson-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

The sentence could also mean to be changing topics in itself. It could be interpreted as we are using semicolon to change the path of the conversation; which in itself is the meaning of **semicolon**.

But the sentence would be *best* written as using 'fullstops' and by changing its structure.